# c# interop Excel - disable or remove automatic page breaks

Tags: c#, excel

Since I need only manual page breaks in my Excel application, I'm trying to remove the vertical automatic ones. My researches provided a lot of suggestions, but somehow nothing really worked. I've seen code snippets like

`sheet.VPageBreaks.Clear()`
or
`sheet.VPageBreaks.RemoveAt(int)`

but there are no Clear or RemoveAt methods. I guess this is from an older version. I've seen there's a `Zoom` property, which can be used to display everything on one page, but that's not what I need. There are also two Properties `FitToPagesWide` and `FitToPagesTall` which are used in combination with the `Zoom` property.

The last thing I tried was to set the PageBreak property to `sheet.Cells.PageBreak = (int)Excel.XlPageBreak.xlPageBreakManual` but this results in an exception.

> unable to set the page break property of the range class

I'm out of ideas and out of research suggestions. I need the page breaks, but I want to set them manually, not automatically by Excel. Does anyone have any experience with this?

I'm using C# and the Office Interop library like `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

**EDIT**

The xlsx is created by the code, it's not from an existing file. I create it this way:

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();    
Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add("");
Excel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
```

Comment: Excel Interop calls the same API used by VBA macros. You can record a macro doing what you want and inspect the code. If the changes you make don't appear in the macro, it probably means they aren't available through either VBA or Interop

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If you'd put that comment as an answer I'll accept it. This helped, it works great now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment of Panagiotis helped a lot. I created a macro and watched the source code of it (for those who struggle with the VB code, I recommend the [Telerik Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) to convert it to C#). I added one line to my code:

```
sheet.VPageBreaks[1].DragOff(Excel.XlDirection.xlToRight, 1);
```

This drags the first vertical page break (in my case it's the only vertical break) to the right.

Note: I already tried `VPageBreaks[0]` which results in an error. This tells me that Interop is not working with zero based index what I didn't know before.

Note II: This code only removes the vertical page break. For the horizontal you need to work with `HPageBreaks`.